# Google sheet Formula to populate Manager name and employee name

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Please help with following:-
I want a formula which will put result in "C" Column. Format is : - Manager name and employee name. Prefix is "1:" before each name. For every team, first name will be of Manager.
If manager name appearing in "Employee" column then entire team name should reflect in same cell or else only employee name.

As of now I am using below formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,"1:"&B3,"1:"&A3,"1:"&A4,"1:"&A5,"1:"&A6)
```

[image]

I want a formula which would populate the details like result shown in C column. I want to map team members to respective managers and need to have prefix "1:" before each name.

Comment: please share a link to the sheet in the screenshot so we don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Sorry could not share link due to company policy restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=MAP(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(",",1,"1:"&x,FILTER("1:"&A2:A,B2:B=x)),"1:"&x)))
```

[image]

Comment: Ok. (tick mark) done